# show success Toast problem

Tags: lightning-web-components, toast

I Used showToast() method to get a success message with a toast when my method work correctly but I get the same toast message even if my method don't return any value (the case when I get an error I have the get the same message ) I don't know where is the problem

```
@track canc = false ;
  myMethod(){
        getName({TemplateId: this.recordId, value : this._selected.toString()})
     console.log('record id is:'+this.recordId);
            console.log('selected is: '+this._selected);
            if(this.canc){
                console.log('success'+this.canc);
                const event = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: '',
                    message: 'successfully',
                    variant: 'success',
                    mode: 'dismissable'        
               });
               this.canc= true;
               this.dispatchEvent(event);
               this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
        
           }else {
        
               console.log('eeeeeroooooooooorrrpopup'+this.canc);
              const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                   title: 'Error',
                   message: 'Please check that all rules are respected',
                   variant: 'Error',
                   mode: 'dismissable'
        
                   });
        
                   this.dispatchEvent(evt);
        
               }  
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put a check for the result returned from the apex method.

```
    myMethod(){
        getName({TemplateId: this.recordId, value : this._selected.toString()})
            console.log('record id is:'+this.recordId);
            console.log('selected is: '+this._selected);
            if(this._selected){
                const event = new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: '',
                    message: 'successfully',
                    variant: 'success',
                    mode: 'dismissable'        
               });
               this.dispatchEvent(event);
               this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
        
            }else {
              const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                   title: 'Error',
                   message: 'Please check that all rules are respected',
                   variant: 'Error',
                   mode: 'dismissable'
               });
        
               this.dispatchEvent(evt);
           }  
        
     }
```

If you want to use this.canc variable then you need to make it true once you get the result.